# IBM MQ - Ability to queue messages during maintenance without stopping channel

Tags: ibm-mq, channel

Hoping someone with MQ knowledge will know if the following is possible ...

Background : we have **one** IBM MQ 7.5 server currently but happy to upgrade if that helps.

Scenario : We have a dedicated channel and queues for a processing application. I'd like a way, on a single MQ Server, to be able to have new messages delivered and for them to queue up in "Messages_IN" during a release then let them through afterwards. I cannot stop the channel that is used as the consuming application will error (lose MQ access) and not work. i.e. sending applications and the processing application currently use the same channel / queues.

Diagram linked below to help explain ...

[MQ options?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o2m7.png)

Is there anyway to have a flow control on a queue that would allow us to control messages not being consumed by an application without stopping the channel? Any new queues / channels / config etc are fine but currently limited to one MQ Server.

Many thanks for anyone who's taken the time to read this and hopefully its technically possible.

Regards

David

Comment: David, You could `GET(DISABLE)` the  `Messages_IN` queue. The "Processing Engine" would need to handle get inhibited errors.  Which component in the diagram will be undergoing maintenance, is it the "System 4"?  If it is "System 4" why can't the message just queue up on the `Messages_OUT` queue?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the comment of JoshMC is your answer. You ned to set the "**GET**" propiertie of the QUEUES "**MESSAGES_IN**" to "**DISABLED**". With that you prevent any aplication of get message from the QUEUE, whe you end your maintenance you need to set the propertie to "**ENABLED**" for enabled applicaiton to gets messages from the queue.